# Two PHP Mail form issues

Tags: php, forms, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm having issues with this PHP Form Mailer...

I have the site [here](http://dev.mpirebooking.com/booking.html).

**This is the HTML for the form...**

```
            <form method="post" id="submitform" action="submitemail.php" >
                        <input type="text" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Your Name" placeholder="First & Last Name" name="name" />
                        <input type="tel" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Phone Number" placeholder="###-###-####" name="phone" />       
                        <input type="email" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" />
                        <input type="email" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Confirm Email" placeholder="Confirm Email" name="email_confirm" />
                        <input type="text" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Ticket Price Low" placeholder="$ Amount" name="low_price" />
                        <input type="text" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Ticket Price High" placeholder="$ Amount" name="high_price" />
                        <input type="text" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Venue Name" placeholder="Where will it be?" name="venue_name" />
                        <input type="text" style="height: 40px;" class="formstyle" title="Event Capacity" placeholder="# of people attending" name="event_capacity" />

                        <textarea name="message" style="height: 90px;" title="Event Description" placeholder="Please describe anything about this event we should know."></textarea>
                        <input class="formstyletwo" type="submit" value="Send">  
            </form>
```

**Here's the PHP...**

```
    $emailerror .= "Your booking form has been submitted. You will hear from us shortly.";

    // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY
    $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:ia");

    $messageproper ="\n\n" .
        "Name: " .
        ucwords($_POST['name']) .
        "\n" .
        "Phone: " .
        ucwords('phone') .
        "\n" .
        "Email: " .
        $_POST['email'] .
        "\n" .
        "Confirmed Email: " .
        $_POST['email_confirm'] .
        "\n" .
        "Low Budget: " .
        $_POST['low_price'] .
        "\n" .
        "Hight Budget: " .
        $_POST['high_price'] .
        "\n" .
        "Venue Name: " .
        $_POST['venue_name'] .
        "\n" .
        "Event Capacity: " .
        $_POST['event_capacity'] .
        "\n" .
        "Event Description: " .
        $_POST['message'] .
        "\n" .
        "\n\n" ;

        $messageproper = trim(stripslashes($messageproper));
        mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );
}
?>

<div id='emailerror'>
    <ul>
        <? echo $emailerror; ?>
    </ul>
```

The form works ok.

1. I'm trying to get a message to display that says, "***Your booking
   form has been submitted. You will hear from us shortly.***", but
   it's not working.
2. The other issue is I want to make each field a required field. I
   found information on making the email field required, but not
   others.

Can you help?

Comment: Do you want the message to appear, when the email is sent only?

Comment: Yes. On submit, the message displays...

Comment: So, what is the problem. Just do `if(mail())`  then show something

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit_button_name"])){
mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );
echo "Your booking form has been submitted. You will hear from us shortly.";
}
else{
echo "An error occured.";
}
?>
```

To make the form required, just place required in the input.

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" placeholder="Example" required>
```

You're welcome.

Comment: That's not correct, if you get an error on the `mail` function then the message will be displayed anyway. The correct is `if (mail(....)) echo "Your booking...."`

Comment: That's not his problem. What he wants is to echo the success message after sending the email. My code does that. Simple. It has nothing to do with email error, I just copied and pasted his email format.

Comment: No, your code show the message even if the mail didn't sent. If `mail` gets an error then the message has not been sent and you will show the message. Check comments